# How can I use a UIKit ViewController inside Flutter Plugin code?

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin

I'm trying to use `UIDocumentPickerViewController` in the same way as [this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/providing_access_to_directories). When I try to use the example code in the plugin, I get the following errors:

```
flutter_download_manager_darwin/ios/Classes/SwiftFlutterDownloadManagerDarwinPlugin.swift:16:15: No exact matches in call to initializer 
flutter_download_manager_darwin/ios/Classes/SwiftFlutterDownloadManagerDarwinPlugin.swift:16:15: Found candidate with type '([URL]) -> UIDocumentPickerViewController'
flutter_download_manager_darwin/ios/Classes/SwiftFlutterDownloadManagerDarwinPlugin.swift:16:15: Found candidate with type '([URL]) -> UIDocumentPickerViewController'
flutter_download_manager_darwin/ios/Classes/SwiftFlutterDownloadManagerDarwinPlugin.swift:16:72: Type 'Array<URL>.ArrayLiteralElement' (aka 'URL') has no member 'folder'
flutter_download_manager_darwin/ios/Classes/SwiftFlutterDownloadManagerDarwinPlugin.swift:21:41: Cannot find 'startingDirectory' in scope
flutter_download_manager_darwin/ios/Classes/SwiftFlutterDownloadManagerDarwinPlugin.swift:25:11: Cannot find 'present' in scope
```

Here is the exact code:

```swift
import Flutter
import UIKit

public class SwiftFlutterDownloadManagerDarwinPlugin: NSObject, FlutterPlugin {
  public static func register(with registrar: FlutterPluginRegistrar) {
    let channel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "flutter_download_manager_darwin", binaryMessenger: registrar.messenger())
    let instance = SwiftFlutterDownloadManagerDarwinPlugin()
    registrar.addMethodCallDelegate(instance, channel: channel)
  }

  public func handle(_ call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) {
      switch call.method {
      case "pickDirectoryUrl":
          // Create a document picker for directories.
          let documentPicker =
              UIDocumentPickerViewController(forOpeningContentTypes: [.folder])
          documentPicker.delegate = self


          // Set the initial directory.
          documentPicker.directoryURL = startingDirectory


          // Present the document picker.
          present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
      default:
          result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[init(forOpeningContentTypes:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller/3566732-init) is supported in iOS 14.0+, while most likely the minimum iOS version that your app supports is lower.

Comment: I've set the minimum version to iOS 14 and the issues still persist. Interestingly, when I try to type `forOpeningContentTypes`, autocomplete says that the initialiser isn't available in the current context: https://i.imgur.com/6ePHqiF.png